# When is $a^{2^n}+1$ prime finitely often unconditionally?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Define generalized Fermat numbers following [OEIS](http://oeis.org/wiki/Generalized_Fermat_numbers) and [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFermatNumber.html).

For natural $a,n$ and $a$ even, the generalized Fermat number (GFN) is 
$F_n(a)=a^{2^n}+1$.

Very large GFN primes are known (in the largest known primes).

For fixed $a$, GFN can be prime finite number of times for trivial
reasons.

If $a=a'^k$, where $k$ is not a power of $2$, then
$a'^{k\cdot2^n}+1$ factors over $\mathbb{Z}[a']$.

> Q1 Except for this case, are there other even $a$ for which it is known (unconditionally) that $F_n(a)$ is prime only finitely often?

According to folklore conjecture and heuristic arguments, 
this is true for all $a$.

This well might be open, so citable reference will be appreciated.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I mean fixed **even** $a$. For $a=2$ the GFN is Fermat numbers per definition.

Comment: OK, I see, there is a great difference between "can be prime finite number of times" and "cannot be prime infinite number of times"...

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I am also interested in being composite infinite number of times for fixed even $a$ not in the exceptional form. Is this known (maybe this is another question)?

Answer (score 3):

I am almost copy - pasting a book of Sierpinski right now (I think the latest version of it)

> "A. Schinzel showed that for every $a\in \mathbb{N}$ with $1<a<2^{27}$
>   there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^{2^n}+1$ is composite.
>   *Colloq. Math,10,1963,pp. 137-138*
>   BUT, we don't know if there is such an $n$ for every $a$."

So , I suppose that even a weaker form of the question (that at least once the result is composite if $a$ is even) is still an open problem.

Comment: Thanks. Is the book freely available online? And is this the exact title or is abbreviated? I suppose they exclude the trivial given exceptional set?

Comment: Yes I found it here it appears at page 67 of the book.http://www.scribd.com/doc/26892740/250-Problems-in-Elementary-Number-Theory